# Refactoring methods that use the same code but different methods inside

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some methods that are the same except one row (i call different methods on the object client).
I will have more methods like this.

Is there any solution to this except using  Reflection ?

```
 private void initClerks(Client client)
            {
                string[] pks = client.ClerksPKS.Trim(','). Split(',');

                foreach (string pk in pks)
                {
                    string data = JObject.Parse(DBUtils.GetData(Constants.DBProcedures.GetProcedures.GetWorkerDetailsByPkid, pk))[Constants.ResponseJson.Data].ToString();

                    client.addClerk(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Clerk[]>(data)[0]);

                }

            }


private void initManagers(Client client)
            {
                string[] pks = client.ManagerPK.Trim(',').Split(',');



                foreach (string pk in pks)
                {
                    string data = JObject.Parse(DBUtils.GetData(Constants.DBProcedures.GetProcedures.GetWorkerDetailsByPkid, pk))[Constants.ResponseJson.Data].ToString();
                    client.addManager(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager[]>(data)[0]);

                }

            }
```

Comment: You parse JSON string, and then convert it back to a string, and then deserialize it...

Comment: "are the same except one row (i call different methods on the object client)" - I count three differences - how `pks` is initialised, yes, the `client` method, but also the type parameter for `DeserializeObject`.

Comment: Well, to me this seems to more like workaround over another problem which is the way you store your primary keys (pks?) and get the data. You could maybe enhance those to gain better control over initialization process.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by passing an action into a method. Something like

```
private void actOnData(Client client, string[] pks, Action<Client, string> addThing)
{
    foreach (string pk in pks)
    {
        string data = JObject.Parse(DBUtils.GetData(Constants.DBProcedures.GetProcedures.GetWorkerDetailsByPkid, pk))[Constants.ResponseJson.Data].ToString();
        addThing(client, data);
    }
}

private void initClerks(Client client)
{
    string[] pks = client.ClerksPKS.Trim(',').Split(',');
    actOnData(client,pks,(c,d) => { c.addClerk(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Clerk[]>(d)[0]); });
}

private void initManagers(Client client)
{
    string[] pks = client.ManagerPK.Trim(',').Split(',');
    actOnData(client, pks, (c, d) => { c.addManager(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Manager[]>(d)[0]); });
}
```

Comment: I like your solution,it is exactly what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Taking into account this is not external legacy lib I would suggest refactoring Client class as well to simplify its API (I would change more but let's stop at some point)

pseudocode:

```
// taking into account Client, manager all are workers
class Client
{
    // further whenever you need filter out managers use LINQ OfType<>
    List<Workers> workers;

    public void Add<T>(T worker) where T: Worker
    {
        workers.Add(client);
    }
}
```

See [Extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) approach,

```
private void Initialize<T>(Client client, string[] pks)
{
    foreach (string pk in pks)
    {
        string data = JObject.Parse(DBUtils.GetData(Constants.DBProcedures.GetProcedures.GetWorkerDetailsByPkid, pk))[Constants.ResponseJson.Data].ToString();
        client.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(data)[0]);    
    }
}

private void initClerks(Client client)
{
    string[] pks = client.ClerksPKS.Trim(',').Split(',');
    Initialize<Clerk>(client, pks);
}

private void initManagers(Client client)
{
    string[] pks = client.ManagerPK.Trim(',').Split(',');
    Initialize<Manager>(client, pks);           
}
```

And going forward thsoe two intiClerks/initmanagers looks redundant, just inline calls to `Initialize` (surely if entire code base not more complex than you shown here)

Comment: He is calling addClerk and addManager, so can not just extract the foreach.

Comment: Also `DeserializeObject<Clerk[]>` vs `DeserializeObject<Manager[]>`. As I said in my comment to the question, I count *three* differences rather than one.

Comment: Oh man missed that, my apologizes. Added generic type parameter, and there another issue with addManager() call will fix this

Comment: @sll, you still have the addManager, that and addClerk should be refactored to overloaded methods for this to work.

Comment: @Maxim: please show how client.AddManager, AddClerk looks like?

Comment: @sll it's just  adding an object a list

Comment: adding to different lists right? like Lis<Client> but different ones? If yes what about having marked interfaces IManager, IClerk and using single list? And wondering if manager and clerk all have the same properties so you're ok with single class Client

Comment: they both inherit from Worker class, i have one worker list,sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: I updated code, let me know if it's fine, main point - no need for two methods AddManager, AddClerk, but it's up to you, you can leave two methods then more refactoring might be required and personally I wouldn't mess up code with parameters like proposed Action<> to pass insertion to a list, in such simple case better to rely on simple OOP

Comment: you are right,at first i had addWorker but my partner decided to change this ...,thanks a lot

Comment: NP, all such issues comes form somewhere wrongly made design decisions. I see all your code does it's take some IDs (pks) form an object, then create set of new objects and add them to the same Client, this might be simplified much more further, think about Single Responsibility principle and messing up data enities with business logic, then you find a way to rework solution, all other work arounds like passing complex Actions or adding more AROUND intiially wrong design would complicate things further, you should SOLVE not work around whenever possible

Comment: @sll no doubt that refactoring is required, I have asked this question just to understand the principle,and now i see many solutions to the problem.about the pk's,as you said it is saved like this in the database.i need to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The typical path for extracting a method is to find the differences and declare a corresponding method arguments. Let take your `initClerks` method and find the word `Clerk` inside. There are 3 of them, one being a `Type`, so we'll make a generic method with generic argument `T` corresponding to `Clerk`. The mapping will be something like this

(1) `client.ClerksPKS` maps to `Func<Client, string>`
(2) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Clerk[]>` maps to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>`
(3) `client.addClerk` maps to `Action<Client, T>`

So the common method becomes

```
void Init<T>(Client client, Func<Client, string> getPKS, Action<Client, T> addItem)
{
    string[] pks = getPKS(client).Trim(','). Split(',');
    foreach (string pk in pks)
    {
        string data = JObject.Parse(DBUtils.GetData(Constants.DBProcedures.GetProcedures.GetWorkerDetailsByPkid, pk))[Constants.ResponseJson.Data].ToString();
        addItem(client, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(data)[0]);
    }
}
```

and the usage

```
private void initClerks(Client client)
{
    Init<Clerk>(client, c => c.ClerksPKS, (c, x) => c.addClerk(x));
}

private void initManagers(Client client)
{
    Init<Manager>(client, c => c.ManagerPK, (c, x) => c.addManager(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create base class to add the common logic in it base Init method.
then in the class that implements BaseClientInitializer override Insert method. This design pattern is called template method.

```
public abstract class BaseClientInitializer
  {
    private string[] keys;
    public BaseClientInitializer(string[] keys)
    {
      this.keys = keys;
    }
public abstract void Insert(string data);

public void Init()
{
  foreach (string pk in keys)
  {
    var data = JObject.Parse(DBUtils.GetData(Constants.DBProcedures.GetProcedures.GetWorkerDetailsByPkid, pk))[
        Constants.ResponseJson.Data].ToString();
    this.Insert(data);
  }
}   


 }

public class Clerks : BaseClientInitializer
  {
    private Client client;
    public Clerks(Client client) : base(client.ClerksPKS.Trim(','). Split(','))
    {
      this.client = client;
    }

    public override void Insert(string data)
    {
      client.addClerk(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Clerk[]>(data)[0]);
    }
  }

private void initClerks(Client client)
{
     var clerksInitializer = new ClerksInitializer(client);
    clerksInitializer.Init();
}
```

Do the same for init managers. 
The difference is not only in the insert method the pks array is also different: client.ClerksPKS.Trim(','). Split(',') - for clerks and client.ManagerPK.Trim(',').Split(',') for managers. So simply extract method will not work correctly.

Comment: Or just simple object oriented way to extract the common logic into reusable small parts ;)

Comment: @sll Just wait until you see the `ClerksInitializerFactory` that produces `ClerksInitializer`s, and the `BaseInitializerFactory` it derives from!

Comment: @Radin: Every problem has particular level, and solution should be approx on the same level of complexity, otherwise Hello World in OO way might end's up in lots of classes and patterns