# Xamarin: How can I reuse Labels and Entries to avoid creating a lot of classes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reusability

I have a project that has a lot of mathematical formulas and I need to show to users:

I already have a class to solve basic math problems, like sum, subtraction, division, multiplication, etc, and with that, I created a dictionary to change the operator, so it's good.

But I have another class that I do formulas, about 20 formulas, such as Bhaskara, logarithms, geometric sequences, etc. So I'm trying to reuse that entries and labels of these formulas, because if I create formula per formula, it will consume a lot of classes, or one class with a lot of lines.

What's the best way to reuse it? Considering:

- Space in the screen of entries and labels (they change depending of the formulas)
- Quantity of entries and labels to show, e.g:
  Bhaskara have 3 entries (for B², A and C), but the volume of a cube is 1 entry (V = s³), so few entries/labels will not appear.
- Each formula will appear if I click to it appears, they are already doing this, e.g: Solve Bhaskara button will inflate a page with Bhaskara to solve, solve Trigonometry button will inflate the same page, but with Trigonometry to solve, etc, the picture above shows an example.

This is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1gN7.jpg) of how Bhaskara appears on mobile (it only appears the first line, so if I click in the button to solve, it will solve and appear this colorful lines solving Bhaskara), and the code of Bhaskara:

```
void Bhaskara()
        {
            StandardImgExample();

            Label lblDelta = new Label() { Text = delta, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lblDelta, 0, 0);

            Label lblEqual = new Label() { Text = equal, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lblEqual, 1, 0);

            firstEntry = new Entry() { IsVisible = true, TextColor = Color.Black, Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric, PlaceholderColor = Color.DarkGray, Placeholder = "\t b\u00b2 \t", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
            firstEntry.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!firstEntry.Text.Contains("\u00b2"))
                {
                    firstEntry.Text += "\u00b2";                    
                }   
            };
            firstEntry.Focus();

            gridInputs.Children.Add(firstEntry, 2, 0);

            Label lblMinus = new Label() { Text = minus, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lblMinus, 3, 0);

            Label lblFour = new Label() { Text = "4", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lblFour, 4, 0);

            Label lblMult = new Label() { Text = "*", TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lblMult, 5, 0);

            midEntry = new Entry() { IsVisible = true, MaxLength = 9999999, TextColor = Color.Black, Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric, PlaceholderColor = Color.DarkGray, Placeholder = "\t a \t", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(midEntry, 6, 0);

            Label lblMult2 = new Label() { Text = "*", TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lblMult2, 7, 0);

            lastEntry = new Entry() { IsVisible = true, MaxLength = 9999999, TextColor = Color.Black, Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric, PlaceholderColor = Color.DarkGray, Placeholder = "\t c \t", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridInputs.Children.Add(lastEntry, 8, 0);

            firstEntry.Completed += (s, e) => { midEntry.Focus(); };
            midEntry.Completed += (s, e) => { lastEntry.Focus(); };

            Button btnSolve = new Button()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Text = "Solve",
            };
            btnSolve.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstEntry.Text))
                {
                    firstEntry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Red;
                    return;
                }
                else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(midEntry.Text))
                {
                    midEntry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Red;
                    return;
                }
                else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastEntry.Text))
                {
                    lastEntry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Red;
                    return;
                }

                frameFormula.IsVisible = true;
                frameFormula.IsEnabled = true;

                if(!isFirst)
                    await frameFormula.FadeTo(0, 400);

                gridFrame.Children.Clear();

                DisplayFirstLineResult();
                DisplaySecondLineResult();
                DisplayThirdLineResult();
                DisplayDeltaResult();
                isFirst = false;

                await frameFormula.FadeTo(100, 200);
            };
            stackLayoutMain.Children.Add(btnSolve);
        }

        void DisplayFirstLineResult()
        {

            Label lblDelta = new Label() { Text = delta, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Blue, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblDelta, 0, 1);

            Label lblEqual = new Label() { Text = equal, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblEqual, 1, 1);

            firstEntryResult = StringToNumeric(RemovePow(firstEntry.Text));
            firstEntryResult = Math.Pow(firstEntryResult, 2);

            Label lblFirstEntry = new Label() { Text = firstEntryResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Green, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblFirstEntry, 2, 1);

            Label lblMinus = new Label() { Text = minus, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMinus, 3, 1);

            Label lblFour = new Label() { Text = "4", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Purple, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblFour, 4, 1);

            Label lblMult = new Label() { Text = "*", TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMult, 5, 1);

            Label lblMidEntry = new Label() { Text = midEntry.Text, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Purple, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMidEntry, 6, 1);

            Label lblMult2 = new Label() { Text = "*", TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMult2, 7, 1);

            Label lblLastEntry = new Label() { Text = lastEntry.Text, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Orange, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblLastEntry, 8, 1);

        }

        void DisplaySecondLineResult()
        {
            Label lblDelta = new Label() { Text = delta, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Blue, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblDelta, 0, 2);

            Label lblEqual = new Label() { Text = equal, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblEqual, 1, 2);

            Label lblFirstEntry = new Label() { Text = firstEntryResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Green, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblFirstEntry, 2, 2);

            Label lblMinus = new Label() { Text = minus, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMinus, 3, 2);

            midEntryResult = StringToNumeric(midEntry.Text);
            midEntryResult = 4 * midEntryResult;
            
            Label lblMidEntry = new Label() { Text = midEntryResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Purple, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMidEntry, 4, 2);

            Label lblMult2 = new Label() { Text = "*", TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMult2, 5, 2);

            Label lblLastEntry = new Label() { Text = lastEntry.Text, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Orange, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblLastEntry, 6, 2);
        }

        void DisplayThirdLineResult()
        {
            Label lblDelta = new Label() { Text = delta, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Blue, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblDelta, 0, 3);

            Label lblEqual = new Label() { Text = equal, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblEqual, 1, 3);

            Label lblFirstEntry = new Label() { Text = firstEntryResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Green, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblFirstEntry, 2, 3);

            Label lblMinus = new Label() { Text = minus, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMinus, 3, 3);

            lastEntryResult = StringToNumeric(lastEntry.Text);
            midAndlastEntryResult = midEntryResult * lastEntryResult;

            Label lblMidEntry = new Label() { Text = midAndlastEntryResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Purple, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblMidEntry, 4, 3);
        }

        void DisplayDeltaResult()
        {
            Label lblDelta = new Label() { Text = delta, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Blue, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblDelta, 0, 4);

            Label lblEqual = new Label() { Text = equal, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblEqual, 1, 4);

            deltaResult = firstEntryResult - midAndlastEntryResult;

            Label lblFirstEntry = new Label() { Text = deltaResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.Green, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            gridFrame.Children.Add(lblFirstEntry, 2, 4);
        }
```

Comment: extract the common functionality into a base class that the others inherit from.  And use MVVM to separate UI from behavior

Comment: Can you show an example of how can achieve it in my case?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-base-class?view=vs-2019, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/121440/109350, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25438012/199364, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34528201/199364